# JS value name and it's value

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I want to draw chart, I use highchars.js, data I can take from php script, so I have something like this after php `month=["June","July",]` and I need to place it in highchart

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        xAxis: {
            categories : month
        },

...
    });
```

but I see the name of variable, not it's value, is it possible to replace the name of variable with it's value.
I want something like this

```
var month=["June","July",];
    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            xAxis: {
                categories : ["June","July"]
            },

    ...
        });
```

Comment: can you give an example of what you want to do?

Comment: in your case categories will be ["June","July",]...

Comment: i want that categories must be equals to variable month, if i do `categories:month` it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Just use that variable:

```
var month=["June","July",];
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        xAxis: {
            categories : month
        },

...
    });
```

Note: Remove extra comma at the end of array.

Comment: It's combined option of your two in the question.. live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ck93N/3/

Comment: If you don't know how to get variable from PHP, then see answer by Mohammad.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var month=["June","July"];
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        xAxis: {
            categories : month
        },

...
    });
```

And to get rid of the trailing "," you should substr the last character from the variable in PHP code before outputting it in the JS variable,

So if your PHP code had:

```
$month = "[";
while(LoopConditionForTwelveMonthNames) {
    $month .= '"' . $MonthName . '",';
}
$month = substr($month, 0, strlen($month)-1);
$month .= "]";
```

Then you may fix it

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example `highchart.php` script that could output appropriate javascript.

```
<?php
    $month = array("June", "July");
?>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
            xAxis: {
                categories : <?php echo json_encode($month); ?>
            }
   });
```